# Doorkeeper - Skip Authorization Step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I'm building a Chrome extension that accesses my Rails API via OAuth using the Doorkeeper gem (ver. 1.4.0). In the documentation for that gem, it gives pretty clear instructions for how to get the provider app to skip the "authorize application" whenever a new user tries to use the Chrome extension. One just needs to add this to the initializer:

```
  skip_authorization do
    true
  end
```

But I am following the instructions and nothing changes. It still asks the user to authorize the app. Is there something obvious I'm missing here? This is my /initializers/doorkeeper.rb

```
Doorkeeper.configure do

  orm :active_record

  resource_owner_authenticator do
    current_user || warden.authenticate!(:scope => :user)
  end

  default_scopes  :public

  skip_authorization do
    true
  end

end
```

(Everything else is commented out.)

I'm using the Chrome Identity api to access OAuth from the Chrome extension, and currently testing with my provider app running on localhost. Has anyone else had this problem? Is there a step that I'm missing?

Comment: Is it possible it is becuase you are using the scope. `default_scopes  :public`. Try removing that since the default setup should not require it.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible it is becuase you are using the scope. `default_scopes  :public`. Try removing that since the default setup should not require it. Maybe because of the Scopes it asking the user to approve what API are allowed to the client app.